# shell scripting to fetch the file contents

Tags: shell-script, awk

a log file get generated every minute in directory called "data_logs"

log file name :

```
abc.log.2019041607
abc.log.2019041608..
```

contents of the log file like this

```
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:1

R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0 
R_MT|D:1234|ID:413|S:0

k_MT|D:1234|ID:414|S:1
k_MT|D:1234|ID:414|S:1
k_MT|D:1235|ID:413|S:1
k_MT|D:1235|ID:413|S:1
```

I am writting a shell script, which when executed it look for the files which gets created in last 5 minutes(Last 5 files, 1 file gets created every minute), open each file one by one and do process, i.e create a output.txt file which contains,
`R_MT|D:1234|ID:413` for this combination total count having 's' as 0 gets stored in  "submited" column, 's'=1 gets stored in notsubmitted column

my output.txt need to look like this:

```
Type, Number,ID,submitted,notsubmitted
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413,5,10
R_MT,D:1234,ID:414,0,2
R_MT,D:1235,ID:413,0,2
```

I have used this to get the submitted and notsubmitted values:

```
zcat abc.log.2019041607.gz |grep "R_MT"|awk -F"|" '{print $2","$3","$4}'|sort|uniq -c
      5 D:1234,ID:413,S:0
     10 D:1234,ID:413,S:1
      2 D:1234,ID:414,S:1
      2 D:1235,ID:413,S:1
```

by above command i am getting the count but i am not getting how can I assign it to a variable so that i can write into the fields "submitted" and "notsubmitted" in the output file, and I am not getting how to obtain the last 5 minutes files?

please help me in this thanks alot!

Comment: Please only ask 1 question per question. You have 2 completely different questions in there: 1) how to find the last 5 files, and 2) how to manipulate one of the files to get the desired output for that file.

Answer (score 0):

With input.log being your input I have this that works with gawk, still struggling to find out with awk:

```
cat input.log |
 gawk -F"|" \
    #print the header
 'BEGIN{print"Type, Number,ID,submitted,notsubmitted"}
    #only work on non empty lines
 NF>0{ 
     #create an ID from the first three fields
    n=$1","$2","$3; 
        #everytime the ID pops up, increment subindex 1 or 2 depending on the value of field 4
        if($4=="S:1"){
            array[n][2]++}
        else{
            array[n][1]++}
}
     #print the final array
END{for(i in array){
       #if the value has never been seen declare it to be zero
        if(array[i][1]){
            m=array[i][1]}
        else {
            m=0}
        if(array[i][2]){
            n=array[i][2]}
        else {
            n=0}
    print i","m","n}
}'
```

Comment: There is no need to escape the newlines in a single quoted string (and you are not doing it everywhere within the string anyway).  Removing the backslashes on most lines would improve readability.  The newline after a pipe also don't need escaping (the only one that is _needed_ is the one after `-F"|"`, unless you start the single quoted string on the same line).

Comment: Like this you mean ? Apologies for the weird formatting then, I wrote it as single line and was trying to make it look clearer.

Comment: To make it cleaner run `gawk -o- 'your script'` and gawk will pretty-print it.

Comment: Thanks for the info ! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To find the log files modified within the last 5 minutes, you can use `find`.  e.g.

```
find data_logs/ -type f -name 'abc.log.*' -mmin -6
```

That finds the log files which were modified less than **6** minutes ago, which should be good enough for most purposes.  If you need exact precision on the file modification times, use:

```
find data_logs/ -type f -name 'abc.log.*' \( -mmin -5 -o -mmin 5 \)
```

which will find files which were modified either less than 5 minutes ago OR exactly 5 minutes ago.

From `man find`:

> ```
> -mmin n
>     File's data was last modified n minutes ago.
> ```

and:

> Numeric arguments can be specified as
>
> ```
>  +n     for greater than n,
>  -n     for less than n,
>   n     for exactly n.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The cross posted question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57377173/3220113 has been put on hold. I will copy the accepted answer here, the other question can be deleted.

**For one file:**
First make the stream easy for processing with awk (it could be done all in awk, for a slightly better performance):

```
sed -nr 's/\|/,/g;s/(^R_MT,.*),S:([^ ]) *$/\1 \2/p' <(zcat abc.log.2019041607.gz)
```

Result (after adding extra test lines)

```
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:413 0
R_MT,D:1234,ID:414 1
R_MT,D:1234,ID:414 1
R_MT,D:1235,ID:413 1
R_MT,D:1235,ID:413 1
```

And now count them in awk, using array a for the fieldnames.

```
sed -nr 's/\|/,/g;s/(^R_MT,.*),S:([^ ]) *$/\1 \2/p' <(zcat abc.log.2019041607.gz) |
   awk '{a[$1]; if ($2>0) notsub[$1]++; else submit[$1]++;}
        END {for (i in a) print i "," submit[i]+0 "," notsub[i]+0;}
       '
```

For 5 files first determine how you want the results.
Each file a different outputfile: use a loop like

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
   ... <( zcat "${filename}") ...
done < <(find datalogs -type f -name "abc*" -mmin -5)
```

Results from the 5 files added to one sum

```
... <( find datalogs -type f -name "abc*" -mmin -5 -exec zcat {} \;) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to find files according to times you prefer.but for getting the result of that you could use `awk` like this:

```
  awk -F\| '!/^\s*$/{if($4=="S:0"){Arr0[$1","$2","$3]+=1} else {Arr1[$1","$2","$3]+=1}}END{for(i in Arr1){print i,",",Arr0[i],",",Arr1[i]}}'
```

for explanation:

1. -F\|: define `|` as field seperator
2. !/^\s*$/: skip empty lines
3. `if(Clause){Statement}else{statement}`: clear
4. `END{...}`: this block executes when operator riched to EOF